# EditText textCapSentences does not work

Tags: android, android-edittext

I try to make text starts with uppercase first letter.
Using attr inputType

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_user_fname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_size_small"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textPersonName"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_avatar"
        android:hint="@string/add_user_fname"
        android:maxLength="@integer/name_max_length"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
```

and set in code

```
userFnameEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

but nothing works.
All of this places in DialogFragment.

**Updated**
I removed setInputType in code and set only inputType="textCapSentences". It works on Android 4, but doesn't work on Samsung Android 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited** 
Try it in your java file

```
TextView txtCapitalize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCapitalize);
txtCapitalize.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```

Comment: thank you. The problem is with device samsung. On other device it works fine

Comment: what's the difference between InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS and just InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS alone?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. But, I found a solution that help me: Be sure that your "Auto Capitalization" settings is checked on keyboard settings. This works on Nexus 4.

Reference: http://www.ercanbaran.com/textcapsentences-not-working/

Comment: Man, if "Auto Capitalization" is closed from the device settings, edit text don't capitalize... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should add this line captilaize your letter in EditText

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

I hope this is helpful. ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

To inform you `android:capitalize="sentences"` is deprecated, So as suggested by other answers you can either use

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

**OR**

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

Both works ! But one for `sentence` and one for `words`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

and

```
android:capitalize="sentences"
```

remove `textPersonName` from xml.

Answer (score 0):

if  you add both

```
android:capitalize="sentences"
```

and `android:inputType="text"`, in this case it take first and input will not captalized.

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```